# iPhone - The class is not coding compliant for a property that I've removed?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I removed a property called ScrollView from my viewcontroller class.
However, now whenever I try to push this viewcontroller onto the nav controller, I get an error saying:

[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scrollView

I've done and Edit>Find for ScrollView and can't find it anywhere.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Check your nib.  It sounds like you declared it as an `IBOutlet` and connected something to it in Interface Builder.  You've removed the property, so when the nib is deserialised, it can't connect the outlet any more.

Answer (score 1):

It's either what Jim suggested above, or you are loading a viewController with the initWithNibName:bundle: and you are loading an incorrect Nib file...

If you did a copy paste from another point of your code, then it's likely you forgot to update the Nib file.
I often do this and end up with the error you mentioned :P